# IntegrityError at /accounts/verify/ UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.mobile_number

Tags: python, django, django-views

when i try login this error is appear.first i make otp and sent to client then i login him/her.I just used a form to enter the otp code... the program gives an error exactly where I want to enter the code
this is login view:

```
class UserLoginView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
form_class = LoginForm

def get(self, request):
    form = self.form_class()
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        rcode = random.randint(1000, 9999)
        send_otp_code(cd['phone'], rcode)
        OtpCode.objects.create(mobile_number=cd['phone'], code=rcode)
        request.session['login_info'] = {
            'email': cd['email'],
            'mobile_number': cd['phone'],
            'password': cd['password']
        }
        messages.success(request, 'we sent you a code', 'success')
        return redirect('accounts:verify_code')
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})


class UserLoginVerify(View):
    form_class = VerifyCodeForm

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.next = request.GET.get('next')
        return super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, 'accounts/verify_code.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        user_session = request.session['login_info']
        code_instance = OtpCode.objects.get(mobile_number=user_session['mobile_number'])
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            if cd['code'] == code_instance.code:
                user = authenticate(email=user_session['email'], mobile_number=user_session['phone'],
                                    password=user_session['password'])
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.success(request, 'you login successfully', 'success')
                    return redirect('home:home')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'your password or email is wrong', 'danger')
            return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form})
```

this is my error in browser.
The error shown is in the registration section, but I am logging in

[image]